# Counting word occurences

Tags: c++, stl

This is a simple word count program I wrote to play around and get familiar with using `std::map`. Is there anything I can improve upon?

I didn't use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to stop the program because that suspends the process on Linux.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;


int main(){
    std::map<string, int> words;
    cout << "Enter some text. Type "***" to end." << endl;

    std::istream_iterator<string> begin(cin);
    std::istream_iterator<string> end;

    while(begin != end){
        if(*begin == string("***"))
            break;
        words[*begin++]++;
    }
    for(std::map<string,int>::iterator iter = words.begin(); iter != words.end(); ++iter)
        cout << std::setw(6) << iter->second << " " << iter->first << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

> ```
> engie does wut engie wants
> pyro mad  
> engie rek pyro
> pyro go cry
> deny engie u try
> rekt u will get
> ```

Output:

> ```
>  1 cry
>  1 deny
>  1 does
>  4 engie
>  1 get
>  1 go
>  1 mad
>  3 pyro
>  1 rek
>  1 rekt
>  1 try
>  2 u
>  1 wants
>  1 will
>  1 wut
> ```

Comment: In Linux <Ctrl-D> sends EOF to the standard input stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Extracting duplicated literals

The string literal "***" appears twice in the code:
once in the helpful message, and another time when you check for it.
It's not too terrible.
But it would be better to extract to a constant to eliminate duplication:

```
const string endmark("***");
cout << "Enter some text. Type \"" << endmark << "\" to end." << endl;

while(begin != end){
    if(*begin == endmark)
        break;
    words[*begin++]++;
}
```

Another advantage of this is that you only create `string("***")` once.

#### Alias types

Some of the type names are pretty long.
I would recommend to give them shorter aliases, for example:

```
typedef std::map<string, int> wordsmap;
typedef std::istream_iterator<string> istreamiter;
```

#### Limiting variable scope

It's a good practice to limit variables to their smallest possible scopes.
So instead of declaring the `begin` and `end` variables before the loop,
convert it to a `for` loop and declare it there.

```
for (istreamiter iter(cin), eos; iter != eos;) {
    if (*iter == endmark) {
        break;
    }
    words[*iter++]++;
}
```

I also renamed the loop variable, because `begin` was not a good name for an iterator, and `eos` is a more commonly used name for *end-of-stream*.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use double quotes in a string literal like this:

> ```
> cout << "Enter some text. Type "***" to end." << endl;
> ```

(The syntax-highlighting even changes the color of the `***`.)

In order to print them out, you have to escape them as such:

```
cout << "Enter some text. Type \"***\" to end." << endl;
```

I suppose your compiler ignored the original, as I got an error when I tried it.

See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) for more info on escape sequences in C++.

Answer (score 5):

I personally would tighten the input loop:

```
static std::string const  endmark("***")

...

for(;(begin != end) && (*begin != endmark);++begin)
{
    words[*begin]++;
}
```

The for the output loop I would use std::copy.

```
for(std::map<string,int>::iterator iter = words.begin(); iter != words.end(); ++iter)
    cout << std::setw(6) << iter->second << " " << iter->first << endl;

... 
std::copy(std:begin(words), std::end(words), std::istream_iterator<WordCount>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

You just need to define an output operator for WordCount.

```
typedef std::map<string,int>::iterator WordCount;
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, WordCount const& item)
{
     return stream << std::setw(6) << item->second << " " << item->first;
}
```

I would avoid `std::endl` unless you really want to flush output (usually not the case). Prefer to use `"\n"` in its place.

Comment: What is the significance of using `std::copy`?

Comment: What do you `significance`? Its just what I would do.

Comment: Okay. It just seems to make the program more complex. I don't `significance`...

Comment: It looks simpler to me. I removed a loop. And made printing count object into a separate function. Both of which make it simpler to read/maintain. Then by using a standard algorithm rather than a hand written loop I have guaranteed the most efficient loop implementation.

Comment: The for loop was more intuitive for me, but that is probably because I haven't had as much experience with C++ as you. Nonetheless, I really appreciated you reviewing my code.

Comment: @EngieOP: Yes, it is better than using a loop as you don't have to worry about bounds-checking and using the correct counter type.  If you can avoid a loop, then do so.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what Jamal said. I went through my code again and decided I should change the `for` loop.

Instead of using `std::map<string,int>::iterator iter` I should probably do: `std::map<string,int>::const_iterator iter`

Or even better just: `auto iter`

Comment: If you can use `auto`, use the `for (auto const& item: words)` variant of the for loop. Then you don't need the iterators at all.